# I want to get input value without id

Tags: javascript, html

In this code, I want to get input value by javascript, How can I do?
Thanks.

```
<div id='my-id' class='my-class'>
    <div>
        <input type='text'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So querySelector or getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is querySelector

```
document.querySelector("#my-id input")
```

Old way is getElementsByTagName

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
document.getElementById("my-id").getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
```

If your element is in a form, you can go old school with

```
document.forms[0].elements[0]
```

Comment: Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
```

Comment: getElementsByName? Where is the name?

Comment: Sorry, meant `getElementsByTagName`. Fixed it now. But actually, you should probably just add an id and get it via the id.